# 2 way SSL authentification on expose FDC webservice

Tags: webservices, authentication, ssl

My client calls a webservice on Salesforce (server), first i send him my certificate (server) and then i would like him to send me back a client certificate ( two way ssl) how do I implement that?

thanks in advance

Comment: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL                                                   The above wiki may help you!